# Difference between "zeros" and "zeroes"

Tags: differences, word-usage, grammatical-number, orthography, numbers

Are there any differences between “zeros” and “zeroes”? Is any of them more correct, more often used, more modern? Are there differences e.g. between British English and American English in the usage of the two forms?